# Updated triggering record with value from related record

Tags: visual-workflow, after-trigger

I have a Flow that gets triggered when a User Lookup field (Support Specialist User) is changed/set. In an After-Update Record element two fields on the same record should be updated with the user.id and user.name of the lookup user that was just set. It seems to work with the ID but not the name, i.e. the support user id is set but the specialist name stays blank.

[image]

Do I still need to do a Get Record first? Can't we simply drill down by now?

At some point I was thinking maybe another process was overwriting the name value in an instant but if I set the user ID to the name it sticks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pull the name in by its parts rather than using the 'full name'. Create a formula in the Flow that pulls in User FirstName and LastName (User.FirstName &" " & User.LastName or something like that), then map that to your Support_Specialist_Name.

Comment: Indeed, this works. Thank you! Do you have an explanation for this behavior?